# define a mouse leave area

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseleave

I have a maze that the user can traverse by dragging his mouse through the path.

I want the maze to refresh only when the mouse leaves the main area, not when the mouse leaves the smiley area, since it possible for the user to start the maze from another position than the starting position.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/49/)

```
$('#highlight_lose').bind('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead `.bind()` as you are using 1.8+ jQuery library

**// Update**

```
$('#highlight_lose').bind('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);  
    $(".white").html("START HERE!");
})

$('#finish').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#highlight_win').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
})

$('#highlight_win').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    $('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/51/)  `-- >` [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/53/)

Comment: Did you see the demo?

Comment: sure... @Dhaval Marthak

Comment: after the sad smiley shows up i can steal start the maze from square "1" as i example for u here- http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/54/

Comment: @alonblack You need to set an overlay along with the Sad smiley. Either increase the area of the smiley so that user can't move mouse over the _ways_